# How can I customize Blazor WebAssembly Msal auth to store token in localStorage instead of sessionStorage?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

## Context

I am working off the [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1) guide to enable client-side authentication in my Blazor WebAssembly app (there is no server-side component, the entire app runs in the browser). The setup works as expected, I am able to redirect users to the AD B2C user flow, log in, and redirect back into my app with the user properly authenticated.

## Problem

The default authentication behavior persists the JWT token retrieved from AD B2C inside of `sessionStorage`, which clears as soon as the browser window is closed. I would like to customize this default functionality to instead persist the token to `localStorage` for longer-lived auth sessions—I'd love to keep the user logged in to subsequent visits after they close the browser window. The docs don't seem to provide any info on how I might accomplish this.

I've also taken a look at the [Additional Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#save-app-state-before-an-authentication-operation) docs to under how the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` might be customized, but was unable to find any info related to how these tokens are stored and retrieved.

I appreciate any guidance on this!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have figured it out by browsing the [MSAL.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso) docs: there is a `cacheLocation` config property that can be set to **localStorage**, and `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal.Models.MsalProviderOptions` exposes that property.

To get it working, I simply added the following to **Program.cs**:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
    ...
});
```

Comment: For me, this works for a few hours until my token expires, but the Msal library doesn't seem to automatically get a new token. Do you have the same experience? 

Even after I manually try to sign out with `await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();` any pages that I decorate with an `[Authorize]` attribute, still get routed to my NotAuthorized view.

The only way I can get a new token is if I completely clear localStorage in my browser.

Comment: @Dave are you requesting the `offline_access` scope for your token?

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper, my comment was from over a year ago. I don't remember what I did to solve it.

Comment: @Dave - did you actually find a way to automatically request a new access token? We are working on this exact same problem, and we are concerned MSAL isn't smart enough to keep reusing the old refresh_token when access expires in 1 hr (aka, can you give it a quick check if you still have access to your solution?)